# Splitting a string like shell would

Tags: python, string, shell

I'm reading a line from a file that looks something like this

```
key1=4 key2="Hello World"
```

I would like to split that into the list

```
['key1=4', 'key2=Hello World']
```

Is there a simple way to do this shell-like processing in Python without having to walk the string searching for the next `' '` or `'"'` and incrementally processing it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a dictionary? {'key1': 4, 'key2': 'Hello World'}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = 'key1=4 key2="Hello World"'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['key1=4', 'key2=Hello World']
```